# Laravel Echo "Echo is not defined"

Tags: laravel, echo, pusher

First of all thanks for reading. Let me explain the problem that I'm facing. So I installed Pusher and Laravel Echo successfully and tried to use it in my `dash.blade.php`, this is how I imported the `app.js` file: `<script src="{{ asset('js/app')}}"></script>`. After that I used this:

```
<script>
  Echo.channel('channelDemoEvent')
    .listen('eventTrigger', (e) => {
      alert('Its working');
    });
</script>
```

And when running it I get this error in chrome console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Echo is not defined`

I searched on the internet for this error more than 2 hours now, and when I added `window.` before the `Echo` I got a different error, that error is this: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined`

I have tried to comment these on the `app.js` because I read that that could make this error: `Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));`
`window.Vue = require('vue');`

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
});`
```

After commenting those I get the same error.
Thanks for reading & have a nice day.

Answer (score 8):

## Here are the steps

### composer

Install pusher if you are using pusher

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~4.0"
```

### NPM or Yarn

```
npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js
```

If not using pusher then

```
npm install --save socket.io-client
```

### Blade

Make sure that your template has csrf token like so

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

### .env

In .env you should fill in your pusher information

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=yourpusherappid
PUSHER_APP_KEY=yourpusherappkey
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=yourpusherappsecret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=yourpusherappcluster

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

### webpack.mix.js

In webpack.mix.js

Make sure you have

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
require("dotenv").config();
```

### bootstrap.js

In resources/js/bootstrap.js

Make sure you have uncommented

```
/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

import Echo from "laravel-echo";

window.Pusher = require("pusher-js");

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "pusher",
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true
});
```

### Compile

Don't forget to recompile your js files

```
NPM run watch 
NPM run dev 
NPM run prod
```

### Config Cache

Sometimes you may need to clear the cache so that changes take effect run the following command

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Thanks for upvote

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was in loading Echo Script before initialization,
So i had to make the listener start after the whole page is loaded

```
window.addEventListener('load',  () =>{
   Echo.join(`chat`)
    .here((users) => {
       console.log(users)
    })
      .joining((user) => {
          console.log(user.name);
         })
      .leaving((user) => {
           console.log(user.name);
           })
      .error((error) => {
              console.error(error);
       });

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you can check/do that might resolve your issue:

- Make sure that you have uncommented these lines in `bootstrap.js`

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true
});
```

- Did you run `npm run dev`, `npm run prod` or `npm run watch` after making your changes?
- I am not confident with your js importation. `asset('js/app')` will return `http://localhost/js/app`. You probably have to add `.js` at the end to have everything imported properly.
- Check that your `js/app.js` importation is positioned *before* your `<script></script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Laravel echo in pure JS and that happened because document wasn't loaded.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        Echo.listen(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the below sequence of code

1. first set window variable
2. second config vue

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'socket.io',
  host: 'http://127.0.0.1:6001'
})
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
`
```